# Differential "Freshman's dream" for Laplacian operator.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Today I encountered quite an interesting phenomenon. There is an exercise in multivariable calculus that asks students to prove the identity
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} = e^{-2\xi} \left( \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \xi^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \theta^2} \right),
$$
where the coordinates transformation is given by $(x,y) = F(\xi,\theta) = (e^\xi \cos(\theta), e^\xi \sin(\theta))$, assuming $f \in C^2$. I have seen a person misunderstood the question and proved
$$
\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right)^2 = e^{-2\xi} \left( \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi} \right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \right)^2 \right)
$$
instead. To my surprise, his proof contains no mistake and the misinterpreted equation is actually true!

This got me into thinking about the generalization of the above "Freshman's dream" for Laplacian operator:

> Which coordinates transformation $(x,y) = F(\xi,\theta)$ (or, equivalently, $(\xi,\theta) = G(x,y)$ )has the property that for any $f\in C^2$, we have
> $$\begin{align}
> \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} &= h(\xi,\theta) \left( \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \xi^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \theta^2} \right) \\
> &\text{if and only if} \\
> \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right)^2 &= h(\xi,\theta) \left( \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi} \right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \right)^2 \right)
> \end{align}$$
> on an open domain $D\subset\Bbb R^2$ for some (sufficiently smooth) function $h>0$?

---

Here's my thought so far:

Suppose that our coordinates transformation is given by $(\xi,\theta) = G(x,y) = (G_1(x,y),G_2(x,y))$. By some calculation (that I shall skip), we can compute that the Laplacian $\Delta = \partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2$ in the coordinate $(\xi,\theta)$ can be written as
$$
\partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2 = (\Delta G_1)\partial_\xi + (\Delta G_2)\partial_\theta + |\nabla G_1|^2 \partial_\xi^2 + |\nabla G_2|^2 \partial_\theta^2 + 2(\nabla G_1 \cdot \nabla G_2)\partial_\xi \partial_\theta,
$$
hence $\partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2 = h(\partial_\xi^2 + \partial_\theta^2)$ if and only if
$$
|\nabla G_1|^2 = |\nabla G_2|^2 = h, \quad \Delta G_1 = \Delta G_2 = 0, \quad \text{and}\quad \nabla G_1 \cdot \nabla G_2 = 0.
$$
On the other hand, we have
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\partial_x f &\partial_y f \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\partial_\xi f &\partial_\theta f \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}\partial_x G_1 &\partial_y G_1 \\
\partial_x G_2 &\partial_y G_2 \end{pmatrix},
$$
hence in order that $(\partial_x f)^2 + (\partial_y f)^2 = h ((\partial_\xi f)^2 + (\partial_\theta f)^2 )$, we need the Jacobian matrix to be of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\partial_x G_1 &\partial_y G_1 \\
\partial_x G_2 &\partial_y G_2 \end{pmatrix} = \sqrt{h}\ M,
$$
where $M$ is an orthogonal matrix at each point on $D$. In particular, this is equivalent to
$$
|\nabla G_1|^2 = |\nabla G_2|^2 = h \quad \text{and}\quad \nabla G_1 \cdot \nabla G_2 = 0.
$$
It seems like the "miracle" we have seen earlier is a little bit less surprising than expected!

---

From my calculation above (unless I made some mistakes), it seems like
$$\begin{align}
\partial_x^2 f + \partial_y^2 f &= h(\partial_\xi^2 f + \partial_\theta^2 f) \\
&\text{if and only if} \\ 
(\partial_x f)^2 + (\partial_y f)^2 &= h ((\partial_\xi f)^2 + (\partial_\theta f)^2 ) \ \ \text{and} \ \ \Delta G_1 = \Delta G_2 = 0, 
\end{align}$$
i.e. $G$ is a harmonic function coordinate-wise. In particular, this is true for our original coordinate transformation function since we can rewrite $(x,y) = (e^\xi \cos(\theta), e^\xi \sin(\theta))$ as $(\xi,\theta) = G(x,y)$, where
$$
G(x,y) = (G_1(x,y) , G_2(x,y)) = \left( \frac12 \ln(x^2+y^2), \arctan\left( \frac{y}{x} \right) \right).
$$
Here $G_1$ and $G_2$ are indeed harmonic (on an appropriate domain). I want to know if we can find more interesting examples like this? I have a feeling that this should be related to holomorphic functions and harmonic conjugate but my knowledge of complex analysis is pretty limited.

> Is there a general theory that would allow us to construct a coordinate transformation function $G$ satisfying the above properties?

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti I knew it! My guts told me there is definitely something to do with holomorphic function but I didn't take a step further to actually check it. I haven't used any complex analysis for so long that I didn't even recognize the Cauchy-Riemann equation even when it was staring at me right in the face. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

*Summary*. The orthogonality of the matrix $M$ also implies that $\Delta G_1 = \Delta G_2 = 0$, so the two conditions are equivalent. That is, the conditions $|\nabla G_1|^2 = |\nabla G_2|^2 = h > 0$ and $\nabla G_1 \cdot \nabla G_2 = 0$ are quite restrictive and guarantee that either $G_1, G_2$ or $G_1(x, -y), -G_2(x,-y)$ are harmonic conjugates. In either case, $G$ is a conformal change of coordinates. This is part of the proof below, which answers your main question about the class of such coordinate transformations.

*Discussion*. The starting condition you've specified, namely that
$$
\begin{equation} \tag{*}\label{eq:conformal-lap}
\partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2 = h(\xi, \theta) \left( \partial_{\xi}^2 + \partial_{\theta}^2 \right)
\end{equation}
$$ with $G(x, y) = (\xi , \theta) \in C^2$ and $h > 0$, is equivalent to the condition that $(\xi, \theta) = G(x,y)$ is a *conformal change of coordinates*. Geometrically, conformality means that the coordinate transformation *locally* preserves angles, which analytically means that as a complex map, $G : D \to \mathbb{C}$ is (anti-)holomorphic and $\partial_x G, \partial_y G \neq 0$ on $D$.

*Proof*.
("$\Longleftarrow$") To see that this implies the transformation $\eqref{eq:conformal-lap}$, start by noting that by (anti-)holomorphicity, $G_1$ and $G_2$ satisfy either the Cauchy-Riemann equations $\partial_x G_1 = \partial_y G_2$ and $\partial_y G_1 = - \partial_x G_2$, or $\partial_x G_1 = -\partial_y G_2$ and $\partial_y G_1 = \partial_x G_2$. Then in either case, $\nabla G_1 \cdot \nabla G_2 = 0$ and together with $\partial_x G, \partial_y G \neq 0$ we have,
$$
|\nabla G_1|^2 = (\partial_x G_1)^2 + (\partial_y G_1)^2 = (\partial_y G_2)^2 + (\partial_x G_2)^2 = |\nabla G_2|^2 =: h > 0.
$$
Also straightforwardly, $\Delta G_1, \Delta G_2 = 0$. Combined with your computation of $\partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2$ in the new coordinates, we recover the form $\eqref{eq:conformal-lap}$.

("$\Longrightarrow$") In the opposite direction, again as you've noted, $|\nabla G_1|^2 = |\nabla G_2|^2 = h > 0$ and $\nabla G_1 \cdot \nabla G_2 = 0$ together imply that the Jacobian matrix of $G$ is $\sqrt{h} M$ with $M$ an orthogonal matrix on $D$. Since all $2 \times 2$ orthogonal matrices are either of the form $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ b & -a \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ or $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{smallmatrix} \right)$, this implies either the Cauchy-Riemann equations or $\partial_x G_1 = - \partial_y G_2$ and $\partial_y G_1 = \partial_x G_2$ and since $h > 0$ we have $\partial_x G, \partial_y G \neq 0$ on $D$.

$\square$

*Remarks*.

1. Since the coordinate transformations are from Euclidean coordinates, these are also known as *isothermal coordinates*, which speaks to the harmonicity condition on $G_1$ and $G_2$. There is some discussion on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32169/why-are-they-called-isothermal-coordinates) that might be of interest for generalisations to Riemannian manifold settings.
2. In the Riemannian setting, letting $g$ be the Euclidean metric in $(x,y)$ coordinates, $G$ induces a change of metric by its pullback:
   $$
     \begin{align*}
     \tilde{g} &:= G_* g \\
       &= \begin{pmatrix}
           (\partial_x G_1)^2 + (\partial_x G_2)^2 & \partial_x G_1  \partial_y G_1 + \partial_x G_2 \partial_y G_2 \\
           \partial_x G_1  \partial_y G_1 + \partial_x G_2 \partial_y G_2 & (\partial_y G_1)^2 + (\partial_y G_2)^2
          \end{pmatrix}
     \end{align*}
     $$
   and the harmonic conjugate relations (that is, the Cauchy-Riemann equations) imply that $\tilde{g} = h \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$. Then, $\eqref{eq:conformal-lap}$ can be written $\Delta_g = h \Delta_{\tilde{g}}$, which is a form that holds for conformal changes of metric on any [Riemannian surface](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/24934/henry-t-horton) (smooth Riemannian manifolds of dimension two).